# Ticket System - How to create an channel and move to a category in a different channel - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am trying to create a ticketing system where the bot create a channel and put it in a category in a different channel (ex: bot-cmds}

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

@client.command() #or bot
async def ticket(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="category_name")
    if category is None:
        await guild.create_category_channel(name="category_name")

    ticket = await guild.create_text_channel(name=f"{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}'s ticket")
    await ctx.send(f"Here's your ticket #{ticket}")
    await ctx.channel.edit(category=category)
```

But it put the bot-cmds in the category so how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to create the ticket channel in another channels category?

If this is right you can do it like

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

@client.command() #or bot
async def ticket(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="category_name") 
    # Gets the category of that channel (used your version so I don't know if this works)

    ticket = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}'s ticket", category=category) 
    # Creates the text channel in the specified category
    await ticket.send(f"Here's your ticket #{ticket}")
```

Comment: I want to use the "name" not the id so is there another way around it?

Comment: If your version with getting the category per name works, this code now should work

Comment: I just edit your answer by defining guild and it works!

Comment: Right, I forgot and just wanted to add it, but nice that it worked!